# how to make a function of php to POST API in php

Tags: php, post

I want to get the message of a telegram channel, and I found [madeline proto](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/) for that.

But, unfortunately, I did not work with php so I want to implement this function with POST API in php to get By POST API in java.

My question is how? and anyone could give me a reference or code.

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

// Execute for an unlimited time span
set_time_limit(0);

$channel = '@achannel';

while (true) {
    $messages_Messages = $MadelineProto->messages->getHistory(
        ['peer' => $channel,
        'offset_id' => 0,
            'offset_date' => 0,
            'add_offset' => 0,
            'limit' => 0,
            'max_id' => 0,
            'min_id' => 0,
            'hash' => 0 ]);


    $i = 0;
    foreach ($messages_Messages['messages'] as $message) {
        $m = " id: " . $message['id'] . " message: " . @$message['message'] . "%n%";
        #$data = array_push($data, $m);
        #echo $m;
        $i++;
        if($i < 5){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP CURL maybe?

Comment: I found some code in [web] (https://support.ladesk.com/061754-How-to-make-REST-calls-in-PHP) but I do not know how to use it ...

Comment: check my answer as example

Answer (score 0):

Use `PHP CURL`:

Here is an example of `PHP curl`

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "your url",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST", // method
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{}", // your post json
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json", // content type
    "token: your login token if required"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post like this with curl,

```
function post($url, $data)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,["Contenttype:application/json;charset='utf-8'","Accept:application/json"]);

    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: url is the api that you request